# Is it possible to log all the ssh events that would have happened with the router?

Tags: router, cisco

i have a router and two systems . From one system i have logged into the router through hyper terminal . Will it be possible to log the even in the router and view it from my system if someone else tries to log into the same router from the other system using ssh ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 commands in global config mode

```
login on-failure log
login on-success log
```

and now every time someone logs you get:

```
Dec 24 00:00:00.441 CET: %SEC_LOGIN-5-LOGIN_SUCCESS: Login Success [user: hristos] [Source: 10.10.10.10] [localport: 23] at 00:00:00 CET Sat Dec 24 2010
```

For ssh you'll get port 22, and for unsuccessful login you'll also get a message.